Android Duplicate classes from 2 aar libs problem
so before in my android project everything wokrked fine. I had 2 libs in lib folder: for ident and for nuvei. Now I updated identt lib (which i must) and i also must have nuvei latest lib version.
App now can not build and it gives this:
duplicate class found.

    Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class a.b found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class a.c found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.a found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.b found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.c found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.d found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.e found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.f found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.g found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class b.h found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class c.a found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class c.b found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class c.c found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class c.d found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class c.e found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class c.f found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class d.a found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)
Duplicate class d.b found in modules jetified-IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release-runtime (IdenttWebView-1.1.0-release.aar) and jetified-nuvei-cashier-helper-runtime (nuvei-cashier-helper.aar)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

I understand what is happening but unable to solve it. I unzipped both libs and saw that really their folder and classes names collide in same places.
Does anyone have some good ideas. Thanks in advance!
